# JS scope chain, variable scope in an object function

Tags: javascript, function, object, scope, this

I was testing some code just to have a better understanding of variable scope chain in JS.
I’ve set up 2 similar object constructors containing a function that calls a variable from the previous scope.
The results that I get are unexpected from my understanding.

```
var name = "Outter!";
var o = new function () {
                  this.name = "Jill";
                  this.age = 23;
                  this.func = function () {
                                 console.log(name);
                              }
             }
//output to console for: o.func()// Outter!
```

From my understanding I wasn’t expecting this result. Since console.log(name) is trying to access name and name is in the previous scope (the o object’s scope), following the chain path to the upper scope the first name variable that is met, is the one in the o object. Instead the global scope name variable is reference. Basically I was expecting as a result “Jill”.

How come?

Should the invocation of console.log(name) be seen as an invocation to console.log(window.name)?

clearly if I use console.log(this.name), Jill will be the result, but this is not what I'm looking for, I want to know why just "name" isn't working.

Comment: this.name makes it a property of the function, not a variable. so it has nothing to do with the scope chain. the *only* name variable you have defined is Outter.

Comment: further, you should not* be using `new` there either, you just want var o = function () { //...

Comment: @chiliNUT Then he would need to use `o().func()`.

Comment: @Barmar: `(new o).func()`, rather.

Comment: I thought new was to be used before a constructor, and the function constructor is like new Function(arg1,arg2,argN,body). if its going to be accessed as o.func, why even make it a function at all instead of an object?

Comment: *"I want to know why just "name" isn't working."* Because `name` refers to the **variable** `name`, not to a property `name` that might exist on some object (exceptions: global scope and `with` statements). Assigning a property to an object, even if it is `this`, does not impact the scope (chain). Maybe have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

Comment: @Barmar I was thinking it would be something like `o=function () {//..}`;`var instanceOfO=new o();`, `instanceOfO.func` I've never seen new used like that so I'm a little thrown.

Comment: He's just combining the two operations into one. Anything you can do with a variable whose value is a function can also be done using the anonymous function itself.

Comment: ohh gotcha, so its like defining a constructor and constructing it in a single statement

Answer (score 0):

`this.name = "Jill"` doesn't declare a variable named `name`. Instead it defines a key named `name` on the object instance (created by the `new` operator) and sets its value to `Jill`.

If you want your expected result, change `console.log(name)` to `console.log(this.name)` or change `this.name = "Jill"` to `var name = "Jill"`.

Comment: `this.name` won't work, either, because `this` isn't saved in the closure.

Comment: @Barmer It will work. When you assign a method in the constructor as he is, the context is bound. See:
http://jsfiddle.net/jmeyers91/pn8Lk757/